# why doesn't blas work in Anaconda3-2.4.1-Windows-x86_64?

Tags: numpy, pandas, anaconda, blas

```
import numpy

id(numpy.dot) == id(numpy.core.multiarray.dot)
```

When I install Anaconda3-2.4.1-Windows-x86_64 the result is `True` and I find that numpy runs so slow.

When I install Anaconda3-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64 the result is `False` and numpy works well.

In Anaconda3-2.4.1-Windows-x86_64,`numpy.__config__.show()` outputs:

```
lapack_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
blas_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
mkl_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
blas_mkl_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
```

In Anaconda3-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64,`numpy.__config__.show()` outputs:

```
blas_mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Which version of numpy? Did you have MKL installed?

Comment: The version of numpy in Anaconda3-2.4.1-Windows-x86_64 is 1.10.1,and 1.9.2 in Anaconda3-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64.

Comment: how to tell whether MKL is installed?@Paul H

Comment: looks like it's not. this might be just a regression in numpy. create two different environments which each version of numpy and report back if you see a similar discrepancy.

Comment: You can install the MKL optimizations using `conda install mkl`

Comment: thank,@Paul H and  @ali_m.After I execute `conda install mkl`,I get the message:`the following packages conflict with each other:
  - mkl
  - python 3.5*`

Comment: I think Python3.5 does not support this feature yet.